# Handling buttons within UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableView loading cells from a nib. On each table view cell, there are two buttons. When the button is tapped, I need to update other fields in the view that contains the table view.

In the past I've used a delegate on the table view cell to call back to the view controller to tell it that which button was tapped and used tags on the cell to find the cell's index. The problem I'm currently facing is that this sort of behavior happens in multiple places throughout my application and delegate patterns everywhere could get messy quick.

Is there a better method to message the tableview's parent view controller when a button on a specific cell has been tapped? I need to know which cell was tapped and which button on the cell was tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the better method is to make your controller the target of the button's action method. You'll still need to use tags to get the index path of the cell the button was in. You can hook up the action method in IB, or in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: That's ideally what I'd like to do, but currently, the cell doesn't know about the view controller that holds the table view that holds the cell. This is the crux of the problem, the chain goes view controller -> table view -> cell -> button and I need the button to message all the way back up to the view controller, but there is no reference chain to follow all the way up to VC

Comment: I would suggest that you get rid of the nib and make your cells directly in a storyboard. There, you can hook up an IBAction you create in your view controller to a button in the cell. Is there some reason you can't do it this way?

Comment: @skladek, If your cell is complex, you can copy and paste it from the nib to a storyboard so you don't have to remake it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I guess I never considered going that route before. I've always loaded in from a separate nib with its own backing class. I'll try this route. Thanks!

Comment: @skladek, I don't know why you would use nibs any more now that we have storyboards. I really don't see anything you can do in a nib that you can't do just as well (and more conveniently) in a storyboard.